# Showing result of derivative and other functions

Tags: functions, calculus-and-analysis, version-7

I have a problem with my *Mathematica* 7.0
When I write:

```
Derivative[x^2, x]
```

Mathematica returns as result :

```
Derivative[x^2, x]
```

not `2x`

Why is that? Am I doing something wrong with `Derivative`?

Comment: [Reference here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Derivative.html)

Comment: Use `D[x^2, x]` or `Derivative[1][#^2 &][x]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is

```
D[x^2, x]
(* 2 x *)
```

`Derivative` is a representation when the derivative cannot be computed explicitly. For instance look at this example with an unknown function `f`

```
D[f[x],x]//FullForm
(* Derivative[1][f][x] *)
```